# Mi contador de LIKES no funciona

Tags: php, javascript, html, contador

Recibí este código publicado de un compañero aquí en la comunidad, necesito implementar un contador de "ME GUSTA" en mi página web. Un usuario que ya inició sesión puede votar solo una vez por publicación y quería que votara por "ME GUSTA" o "NO ME GUSTA". Pero el código no funciona para ninguna de las opciones. junto a los votos hay un contador que ya debería mostrar el número de votos.
Estoy muy agradecido con los que pueden colaborar, ya lo he comprobado durante mucho tiempo y no estoy avanzando.
Actualizando.. ahora mi sale esta mensaje: "Unexpected string literal '$pub'. Expected a parameter pattern or a ')' in parameter list."

index.html

```
<div id="clickLike">LIKE</div><!-- poner por ejemplo un corazon como en instagram, que se ponga en rojo si el usuario le dio like-->
<span id="totalLikes"></span>



$("#clickLike").on("click",(evt)=>{
  evt.preventDeault();
  $.ajax({
    url : "archivoQueManejaLikes.php",
    method: "POST", //o GET, la diferencia es que se vean los datos o no en el enlace
    data : {
      "idPublicacion" : "algo", /*Asignarle una id, o introducirla en tu html y después recibirla $("elementoQueGuardaId").attr("idAlgo")*/
      "idUsuario" : "algo"/*LA ID DEL USUARIO QUE DA LIKE para que no le dé infinitos*/
    }
  }).done((data)=>{
    //El dato debería ser el número de likes y posiblemente la id del artículo
    var datos = JSON.parse(data); //Es conveniente siempre comunicarse mediante json
    $("totalLikes").text(datos.likes);//por ejemplo
  });
});
```

---

archivoQueManejaLikes.php

````
<?php
include("conecta.php");
if(isset($_POST['idPublicacion']) && isset($_POST['idUsuario'])){
  manejaLikes($_POST['idPublicacion'], $_POST['idUsuario']);
}

function manejaLikes($pub, $usr){
  //primero intentemos saber si el usuario ya dio like en la publicación, a lo mejor lo que quiere es retirarlo
  //saber si han funcionado El delete o el insert
  $operacionDI = false;
  $sql ="SELECT * from likes WHERE id_usuario = ".$usr." AND id_publicacion = ".$pub;
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if($result){
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
      //el usuario ya habia dado like, eliminar el like
      $delete = "DELETE FROM likes where id_usuario = ".$usr." AND id_publicacion = ".$pub;
       $result2 = $conn->query($delete);
        if($result2){
          $operacionDI = true;
        }
    }else{
      $insert = "INSERT INTO likes (id_usuario, id_publicacion) values (".$usr.", ".$pub.")";
       $result3 = $conn->query($insert);
        if($result3){
          $operacionDI = true;
        }
    }
  }
  if($operacionDI){
  $likes = "select count(*) from likes where id_publicacion = ".$pub;
  $resultFinal = $conn->query($likes);
  if($resultFinal){
    $data = [];
    $data['likes'] = $resultFinal->fetch_array()[0];
    echo json_encode($data,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    return; //Si ya tenemos el resultado: salir
  }
}
$dataError= []; //Si llega aquí: ocurrió un error: devolver un JSON!
$dataError['mensaje'] = 'ocurrió un error!';
echo json_encode($dataError,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
}
?>```
````

Comment: Obtienes algún error en el Ajax que ejecutas ?

Comment: Pon un var_dump($_POST)  en el archivo archivoQueManejaLikes.php y verifica en el inspector de tu navegador en el apartado de network o red, ahí aparece el nombre del archivo que dirije el Ajax, y me dices que pone en response, otro punto que veo en tu código y creo que estaría bien que en vez de eliminar y volver a insertar, es verificar si existe el la acción(me gusta o no me gusta) del usuario y la publicación, y actualizar

Comment: Buena idea, la tendré en cuenta para mejorar el código. De la prueba que solicitó, veo que se carga bien las id, pero marcó la siguiente información "Unexpected storing literal '$pub' expected a parapetar patera or a ')' in parapetar List. Solo que no sé lo que significa

Comment: El data que mandas en el Ajax  son números verdad (ID de la publicación, ID del usuario)?

Comment: Otra información que mostró es que: "The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''strict-dynamic''. It will be ignored.
"

Comment: exactamente, los dos numero (INT)

Comment: ¿El mensaje de error `"Unexpected string literal '$pub'...` sale en pantalla (en el HTML) o en la consola del navegador? En el primer caso, podría ser un error de sintaxis/compilación en PHP, en el segundo caso el error estaría en la estructura de la respuesta (que debería ser JSON).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema podría estar en que hay un error en PHP o en el SQL, pero como el código PHP devuelve un error, la llamada AJAX no recibe el JSON esperado, y te sale el error `Unexpected string literal '$pub'. Expected a parameter pattern or a ')` (un error secundario). Para que puedas encontrar el problema original intenta esto:

- Si estás probando con los valores `"algo"` en el AJAX, probablemente la consulta SQL está fallando porque estás concatenando el texto `algo` en la consulta. Prueba mejor con valores enteros.
- En la llamada AJAX, también te conviene agregar algunos `console.log()` para ayudar a localizar el error.
- En PHP, en lugar de concatenar los dos parámetros, deberías usar [parámetros SQL](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). Esto evitaría un error en caso de que el parámetro no sea un INT, y te proteje de [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).
- Por último, asegurate de que incluso/especialmente en caso de error, tu código devuelva un JSON, para que la llamada AJAX pueda reconocerlo, y tenga como programar un mensaje al usuario, o al menos un `console.log()` para tí.

Llamada AJAX:

```
$("#clickLike").on("click",(evt)=>{
  evt.preventDeault();
  $.ajax({
    url : "archivoQueManejaLikes.php",
    method: "POST", 
    data : {
      "idPublicacion" : 12, /* Aunque sean pruebas una un INT */
      "idUsuario" : 17 /* Aquí también */
    }
  }).done((data)=>{
    console.log(data); //Temporal: solo mientras depuras 
    var datos = JSON.parse(data); //
    $("totalLikes").text(datos.likes);//por ejemplo
  }).fail((jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)=>{
    console.log(errorThrown); //Si ocurre un error: enviarlo a la consola 
    //$("totalLikes").text('error?');//opcionalmente avisar al usuario de algún modo 
  });
});
```

En PHP:

```
if($operacionDI){
  $likes = "select count(*) from likes where id_publicacion = ".$pub;
  $resultFinal = $conn->query($likes);
  if($resultFinal){
    $data = [];
    $data['likes'] = $resultFinal->fetch_array()[0];
    echo json_encode($data,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    return; //Si ya tenemos el resultado: salir
  }
}
$dataError= []; //Si llega aquí: ocurrió un error: devolver un JSON!
$dataError['mensaje'] = 'ocurrió un error!';
echo json_encode($dataError,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

### EDITADO:

Sigue este procedimiento:

- Abre la página en el navegador, y abre la consola (F12) (qué navegador usas?)
- En la pestaña Red/Network, has clic en "ALL" (el nombre puede ser diferente, yo uso Chrome)
- Has clic en el botón de LIKE
- En el listado debe salirte el URL de la llamada AJAX, has clic allí para que te salga a la derecha el detalle.
- Allí verás la pestaña "Headers" donde saldrán los parámetros que enviaste, y en "Preview" verás la respuesta de PHP.

Una nota adicional: debes usar  [mysqli_error](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php) cada vez que ejecutes un `$conn->query($sql)` para determinar si hubo un error en SQL y cual fue la causa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias Roimer, hace días que estoy en eso. Pero todavía no me sale nada, hice como dice, me quitó el error, pero no inserta nada en el BD. y mi consola siempre marcar un error así: "The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''strict-dynamic''. It will be ignored." pero no sé si tiene que ve con eso.

Comment: Sobre el error `Content Security Policy`: ¿tienes un script externo (Google, Twitter...) en la página? ¿o un iframe con un URL externo? vi en otra pregunta que el error más bien está en el script externo y no se relaciona con tu caso (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65094328/how-to-fix-content-security-policy-contains-an-invalid-source-error)

Comment: "...pero no inserta nada en el BD" OK. Revisa en la consola del navegador, en la pestana de "Red/Network" qué datos está enviando y recibiendo recibiendo el navegador al ejecutar el AJAX.

Comment: Lo revisé ahora y no aparece nada relacionado con este envío, ni la página donde está el código PHP

Comment: Hice esta prueba y todavía no puedo encontrar nada:
-La única URL encontrada con ajax fue: (ajax.googleapis.com)
Dentro de este no hay envío de información en "Headers" ni recibo en "Preview".
No había nada más relacionado, solo cuatro  "about: blank" que no marca nada.

Comment: Gracias, usar la consola me ayudó y me enseñó mucho. Descubrí que estaba colocando la función ajax dentro de un bucle php, no estoy seguro, pero moverlo resolvió el problema. ¡¡Muchas gracias!!

Comment: De nada! recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta para que la pregunta quede correctamente cerrada.